# How to fix an error when resizing array in c++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, undefined-behavior, c-strings

I have a small program which returns a line of inputted chars:

```
#include <iostream>

char *resize(const char *str, unsigned size, unsigned new_size);  

char *resize(const char *str, unsigned size, unsigned new_size)
{
    char * m = new char[new_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size && i < new_size; ++i) {
        m[i] = str[i];
    }
    delete [] str;
    return m;
}


char *getline()
{
    char ch;
    std::cin >> ch;

    int size = 1;
    char * str = new char[size];
    char * m;

    while (std::cin.get(ch) && ch != '\n') {

        str[size-1] = ch;
        m = resize(str, size, ++size);
        m[size] = '\0';

    }
    return m;
}
```

But it gives me an error :

> Failed test #1. Runtime error terminate called after throwing an
>   instance of 'std::logic_error'   what():  Memory leak or double
>   allocation occured Aborted (core dumped)

I don't fully understand where is the problem, because I'm new in C++. How to solve the problem ?

Comment: Remove your m variable and assign the resize directly back to str

Comment: Use std::string.

Comment: Why don't you just use a [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? or [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)??

Comment: @MikeVine it gives another error
*** Error in `./main': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000000b75090 
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Just in passing, a function definition is also a declaration. There's no need for that initial two-step of declaring the function `resize` immediately before defining it. The definition is sufficient.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am learning c++, the task is for understanding dynamic memory

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: @socm_ I would suggest learning containers and smart pointers instead, rather than manual memory management (which you should generally *avoid* in modern C++).

Comment: ‘str’ is deleted in the first time of the loop. So in the second time of loop, ‘str[size-1]=ch’ cause runtime error

Comment: `char * str = new char[size];` - what `delete[]`s `str`? That looks like a memory leak.

Comment: @bolov -- there's nothing wrong with `new char[size]`. The question your comment links to is about `char data[size]`, which is, indeed, an extension with some compilers.

Comment: @socm_ --  You do know that what you are attempting is nothing more than spaghetti logic in trying to match `new` and `delete` calls.  I wouldn't call that   "learning".  Write an actual string class -- that at the very least teaches proper memory management.

Comment: Manual memory management is an advanced topic you may want to avoid while learning the basics of C++.

Comment: @徐保钰 has the reason. If you got rid of `m` from `getline()` and instead just used `str` you would not have this issue.

Comment: ***Manual memory management is an advanced topic you may want to avoid while learning the basics of C++.*** Sadly education systems teach teach the harder concepts first..

Answer (score 4):

One problem is here: `m = resize(str, size, ++size);`. The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified, so the compiler is allowed to increment `size` before passing the value of `size` as the second argument. Rewrite the code as `m = resize(str, size, size+1); ++size;`.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Maybe could you site a reference for this information?

Comment: It's a partial fix, because the next line accesses out of bounds. if we have started with size=5, then after executing: m = resize(str, size, size+1); ++size; array size is 6 and size=6. then, m[6] = '\0' is accessing the 7th element

Answer (score 3):

Let's analyse some small changes I made to the code:

```
while (std::cin.get(ch) && ch != '\n') {

    str[size - 1] = ch;
    int newSize = size + 1;
    m = resize(str, size, newSize);
    m[newSize - 1] = '\0';
    str = m;
    size = newSize;
}
```

Before you were doing `m[size]` but `size` was already outside the boundaries after the resize.

As Pete Becker noted the evaluation order of the function arguments is unspecified

At the end of the first iteration, `str` points to deallocated memory (you deallocate it in the resize call), I believe you wanted to overwrite it with the pointer `m`.

As noted in the comment, in production code you might want to use `std::string` or `std::vector` or in general some classes that encapsulates the resize behavior for you.

Finally if you never enter the loop, `m` is not initialized and you are returning garbage an uninitialized pointer. Consider initializing to `nullptr`.

Answer (score 2):

This statement

```
std::cin >> ch;
```

is redundant. The character will not be stored anywhere. So this statement should be deleted provided that the line does not have a special format when the first character must be omitted. If you want to remove the new line character stored in the input buffer by some previous input operation then you should do this in the code that calls the function.

There are several problems with this loop.

```
while (std::cin.get(ch) && ch != '\n') {

    str[size-1] = ch;
    m = resize(str, size, ++size);
    m[size] = '\0';

}
```

For starters the allocated array should be initialized

```
char * str = new char[size]{};
```

Otherwise if the first entered character of the user will be the new line character then array will be still uninitialized.

As it was already noted in other answers the order of evaluation function arguments is unspecified. So this call

```
    m = resize(str, size, ++size);
                    ^^^^  ^^^^^^
```

results in undefined bahavior.

Secondly the pointer `str` is not changed in the loop. On the other hand, it is deleted in the first iteration of the loop within the called function `resize`.

This statement

```
m[size] = '\0';
```

tries to access memory beyond the allocated array.

The loop can be rewritten for example the following way

```
int size = 1;
char * str = new char[size]{};

while (std::cin.get(ch) && ch != '\n') 
{
    str[size-1] = ch;
    str = resize( str, size, size + 1);
    str[size++] = '\0';
}

return str;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are accessing an out of bounds element in `m[size] = '\0';`
It should be `m[size-1] = '\0';`

Comment: According to the intended logic of the code, the new size of `m` is supposed to be `size+1`, so `m[size] = '\0'` on its own isn't the problem. (Note: @PeteBecker already pointed out why the code didn't follow the intended logic.)

Comment: @PeteBecker is correct. but his solution does not address the other problem of accessing an out of bounds element

Comment: But the only reason that `m[size]` accesses an out-of-bounds element is because `m` *wasn't* successfully resized to be `size+1` (and @PeteBecker pointed out why that was the case).

Comment: if we have started with size=5, then after executing: `m = resize(str, size, size+1); ++size;`
array size is 6 and size=6.
then, `m[6] = '\0'` is accessing the 7th element because it's zero based

Comment: I see what you mean. I was thinking more in terms of `m[size] = '\0'; ++size;`, while you had it the other way round. (And the original unfixed code *did* increment `size` before using it as an index, as you more or less pointed out.)

Answer (score 0):

This `char* m` is useless, just use the `str` and when you call `resize` the order of argument evaluation by the compiler is not known so do

```
        unsigned newSize=size+1;
        str = resize(str, size, newSize);
        size=newSize;
```

The code can become something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

char *resize(const char *str, unsigned size, unsigned new_size)
{
    char * m = new char[new_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size && i < new_size; ++i)
    {
        m[i] = str[i];
    }
    delete [] str;
    return m;
}


char *getline()
{
    char ch;
    int size = 1;
    char * str = new char[size];

    while (std::cin.get(ch) && ch != '\n')
    {

        str[size-1] = ch;
        unsigned newSize=size+1;
        str = resize(str, size, newSize);
        size=newSize;
        str[size] = '\0';

    }
    return str;
}
int main()
{
        std::cout << getline() << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

But I recommend just using `std::string` because this code is not the most efficient or nice looking.